# Titles with de jure vassals transforming into titular titles

Tags: crusader-kings-2

In my current game I won the crusade for the Kingdom of Andalusia which owned about 75% of the land in Iberia for hundreds of years. During inspection of my new holdings. I noticed many of the kingdoms in Iberia were titular. My two questions are:

- **What is the reason for the Kingdom of Portugal's titular title?**
- **Is there any way to restore it's de jure duchies to this title?**

[image: Titular Kingdom of Portugal]

P.S. I apologize if this is a duplicate, I don't know the name of this mechanism so I was unable to search for an answer on google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De jure kingdoms are not constant. There is a game mechanic called [de jure drift](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/De_jure). When a complete duchy is controlled by a different kingdom than its actual de jure kingdom for over 100 years, that duchy's de jure kingdom changes.

Apparently all of Portugal was conquered by Andalusia for so long that all counties converted to the de jure territory of Andalusia and not a single de jure duchy of Portugal remains.

If you want to revive the kingdom of Portugal, you could give the titular kingdom title to any of your counts or dukes. They will then become king of Portugal and their current holdings will become the new kingdom of Portugal. When they manage to permanently hold their duchies for 100 years, they will become a new de jure kingdom of Portugal (which doesn't need to be anywhere near the "historic" Portugal).

Comment: Just a warning if you do give away the kingdom titles- giving a kingdom-level title to a vassal will make them independent if you don't hold an emperor title.

Answer (score 2):

Philipp explained the mechanics well, so I'll skip to how you can get it back to its original de jure land if that's what you want to do.  Ultimately, for land to drift back into the kingdom the following conditions have to be met:
1.  The full duchy must be owned (either as demesne or through vassals) by one realm.
2.  The owner's liege cannot own the de jure title of the land (in your case, the Kingdom of Andalusia).

Since your character is a King, you'll have to decide whether you will become an emperor or give up the land to vassals.  Both have different risks in terms of getting the land completely back to normal, but both will probably at least allow you to get the titles back to being landed.

If you decide to become an Emperor, you'll need to give the original land of the Kingdom of Andalusia to one vassal, and only that land (at least in Iberia).  Do the same for all the titular Kingdom titles.  At this point, you can leave it alone and if nothing happens, the land will drift back in one hundred years, however, the owner of the Kingdom of Andalusia will have a de jure claim on all the other land in Iberia, so he may decide to fight for what is his.  If you do not have Absolute Crown Authority, there isn't much you can do about this besides combining a few of the smaller northern Kingdoms so their owner can go toe to toe with Andalusia.

If you decide to remain a King, you'll need to do effectively the same as the above, but when you give the Kingdom title to your vassals they will no longer be your vassals.  The one advantage of this is that you can set it up so you are allies with all Kingdoms but Andalusia and always join with the defender when they fight each other until the de jure drift finishes, effectively serving as a peacekeeper.